# Global Precipitation Measurement (GPM) data download in R

Tags: data.gov, programming

I would like to know if resources exist for downloading GPM data in R. I'm aware of the [Hydrological Data Discovery Tools](http://dx.doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.14721) ("hddtools") package, which can be used for accessing Tropical Rainfall Measuring Mission (TRMM) data but does not include a library for GPM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a function to download data IMERG HDF5 and convert them to raster GeoTIFF. You can see the code in https://github.com/AybarCL/GPM-data-management

Comment: Luis    Thanks very much for providing a solution to my question. I will try the code then get back to you. Many thanks.